# AutoIt - How to end a while loop in a GUI with a stop button

Tags: loops, user-interface, while-loop, autoit

I am new to autoIt. I'm sure this is a common question but I searched the forums and haven't had any luck.

I've made a GUI that requires a user input. When the start button is pressed, it begins a while loop with a counter and stops once the counter reaches whatever number the user inputs.

The problem is sometimes I would like to end the script before the counter reaches the number the user inputed. However, the script is unresponsive when I hit the stop button.

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
Opt("GUIOnEventMode", 0)
#Region ### START Koda GUI section ###    Form=c:\users\atkinspr\documents\main1.kxf
Global $main1 = GUICreate("main1", 543, 313, 281, 283)
Global $Input1 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 40, 128, 121, 24)
Global $start = GUICtrlCreateButton("Start", 40, 168, 123, 25)
Global $Label1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Counter: ", 40, 232, 70, 25)
Global $stop = GUICtrlCreateButton("Stop", 200, 168, 123, 25)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
#EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
    Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
    Case $start
            $DataFromUser = GUICtrlRead($input1)
            $i = 0
        while $i < $DataFromUser
           $i = $i + 1
           Sleep(1000)
           GUICtrlSetData($Label1,  "Counter: " &$i)
           ConsoleWrite("output:  " &$i &@LF )
        WEnd
     Case $stop
        Exit
EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Comment: And if you do `Case $stop` **before** `Case $start`? Then it should check if Stop has been pressed before he checks $start.

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra This wouldn't work either, since we're still inside the counter loop.

Answer (score 2):

if you want `GUIGetMsg()` to work properly, you need to avoid adding Sleep in its way.
Here is a quick solution to your problem

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
Opt("GUIOnEventMode", 0)
#Region ### START Koda GUI section ###    Form=c:\users\atkinspr\documents\main1.kxf
Global $main1 = GUICreate("main1", 543, 313, 281, 283)
Global $Input1 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 40, 128, 121, 24)
Global $start = GUICtrlCreateButton("Start", 40, 168, 123, 25)
Global $Label1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Counter: ", 40, 232, 70, 25)
Global $stop = GUICtrlCreateButton("Stop", 200, 168, 123, 25)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
#EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###

Global $Counter = 0

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
        Case $start
            AdlibRegister("Countdown", 1000)

        Case $stop
            AdlibUnRegister("Countdown")
            ConsoleWrite("timer canceled!" & @LF)
            $Counter = 0
    EndSwitch
WEnd


Func Countdown()

    $DataFromUser = GUICtrlRead($Input1)
    $Counter += 1

    If $Counter > $DataFromUser Then
        AdlibUnRegister("Countdown")
        ConsoleWrite("timer ended!" & @LF)
        Return
    EndIf

    GUICtrlSetData($Label1, "Counter: " & $Counter)
    ConsoleWrite("output:  " & $Counter & @LF)

EndFunc   ;==>Countdown
```

Answer (score 1):

The better way: use the OnEventMode.

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>

Opt('GUIOnEventMode', 1)
Global $iCount = 0, $iTimeMax = 0

Global $main1 = GUICreate("main1", 543, 313, 281, 283)
GUISetOnEvent(-3, '_exit')
Global $Input1 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 40, 128, 121, 24)
Global $start = GUICtrlCreateButton("Start", 40, 168, 123, 25)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, '_onClick')
Global $Label1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Counter: ", 40, 232, 70, 25)
Global $stop = GUICtrlCreateButton("Stop", 200, 168, 123, 25)
GUICtrlSetState(-1, $GUI_DISABLE)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, '_onClick')

GUISetState()

While 1
    Sleep(10)
WEnd

Func _onClick()
    Switch @GUI_CtrlId
        Case $start
            GUICtrlSetState($start, $GUI_DISABLE)
            GUICtrlSetState($stop, $GUI_ENABLE)
            $iTimeMax = GUICtrlRead($Input1)
            AdlibRegister('_setLabel', 1000)
        Case $stop
            _stop()
    EndSwitch
EndFunc

Func _setLabel()
    $iCount += 1
    GUICtrlSetData($Label1,  "Counter: " & $iCount)
    If $iCount = $iTimeMax Then _stop()
EndFunc

Func _stop()
    AdlibUnRegister('_setLabel')
    $iCount = 0
    GUICtrlSetState($start, $GUI_ENABLE)
    GUICtrlSetState($stop, $GUI_DISABLE)
EndFunc


Func _exit()
    Exit
EndFunc
```